# How to install opencv-contrib-python with EIGEN on Windows?

Tags: python, opencv, eigen

I can install opencv-contrib-python successfully according to the instruction from the link:

https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/#description.

However, one error occurs when I call the function fastBilateralSolverFilter in my python code.
It says that

***error: (-213:The function/feature is not implemented) fastBilateralSolverFilter :
needs to be compiled with EIGEN in function 'cv::ximgproc::fastBilateralSolverFilter'***

import cv2 works. If I run the command dir(cv2.ximgproc), the function fastBilateralSolverFilter is listed on the screen. I know EIGEN is a math library, but I can't figure out one way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can install OpenCV through anaconda to avoid compiling. The anaconda's OpenCV package is already precompiled with EIGEN.

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```